# tSQLt projects fail to build in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tsqlt

I have a number of database projects using tSQLt that build correctly in Visual Studio 2010. When I open them in Visual Studio 2012, I'm informed that the IDE has to make "functional changes" in order to use them.

Once I let the conversion go through, none of the database projects build successfully anymore. Instead, it seems like ever object in the tSQLt schema raises an error about sys.objects that looks like this:

```
{Path}.Database.Messages\Schema Objects\Schemas\tSQLt\
Programmability\Functions\Private_GetConstraintType.function.sql(6,10):
Error:  SQL71501: Function: [tSQLt].[Private_GetConstraintType] has an 
unresolved reference to object [sys].[objects].
```

The conversion doesn't appear to have changed the named scripts in any way. What's going on? (And how do I investigate a problem like this. It's pretty cryptic.)

Answer (score 3):

tSQLt function **[tSQLt].[Private_GetConstraintType]** selects from **sys.objects** which is located in **msdb** system database.

You need to add database reference to **msdb** (or **master**) database to your Database Project in the Visual Studio 2012 (Data Tools).

To do this go to the *Solution->Project->Reference->Add Database Reference* (see screenshot below)

[image]

and add reference to the system database **msdb**. This should help.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is how I got it working too. I had the very same problem a few months ago. I muddled through and eventually worked it out but I could have done with your answer then! :)

Comment: I also had to add "ALTER DATABASE $(DatabaseName) SET TRUSTWORTHY ON" to my pre-deployment script.

Comment: Oh, and instead of msdb, I had to add the reference to master, setting the database name to sys